# How to concatinate values of two columns and insert concatinated values into one column of another table

Tags: plsql, procedure

**Table :** `SOURCE (Label,SerialNo )`

**Rows:**

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

**Target table :** Target (Concat)

**Expected Rows**

```
1a
2b
3c
```

This needs to be achieved through procedure.

Comment: Use can use CONCAT FUnction to do so and than use insert statement to update the table
SELECT CONCAT(Column2, Column1) AS Combinecolumn
FROM [YOURTABLE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Hi this procedure should satisfy your query.Please let me know if you want anything else. Thanks


    CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE query_answered
AS
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  ( SELECT sr_no||' '||name AS combined_value FROM avrajit
  )
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO av_dup
      (department
      ) VALUES
      (rec.combined_value
      );
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Error captured'||' '||sqlerrm);
END query_answered;

    ----------------------------------
    OUTPUT
    ----------------------------------


    BEGIN
      query_answered();
    END;
```